# Slope Based Texturing

Tags: texture, algorithm, image-processing

On the [main page](https://www.allegorithmic.com/products/bitmap2material/) for Allegorithmic's Bitmap2Material, it mentions that the software uses a **Slope Based** approach over a **Luminance Based** approach. What exactly does this mean?

Comment: Sounds like marketing mumbo-jumbo to me. I would assume "slope-based" means based on the gradient. Usually the gradient is generated from the luminance, though, so who knows?

Comment: You make a good point. I wouldn't be surprised if what you said is true. I'll keep this question open just to see if anybody else has an idea of what it means.